# Question about functions?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

Suppose you have two functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I was able to show that $(f+g)(x) = (g+f)(x) \forall x \in X$, and as far as I can tell both maps have the same domain and codomain. Would it be correct for me to therefore say that $f+g$ and $g+f$ are the same maps? Also, would that terminology to say they are the 'same map' be correct? Because they aren't literally identical, but they do map each element of $X$ to the same element of $\mathbb{R}$. $$\\$$ I ask because I am trying to show that $F(X)$ is a vector space where $F(X)$ is the set of all functions from a set $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. One of the vector space axioms is that $u+v = v+u$ and in the case of functions I assume that you would have to show that for two functions $f,g \in F(X)$ that $f+g$ and $g+f$ are the same map. Is this correct? Sorry if this is basic, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in fact literally identical. A function is given by three pieces of data: a domain, a codomain, and the graph (which determines the image of each element). In this case $f+g$ and $g+f$ have the same domain and codomain, and as you said they map each $x\in X$ to the same number in $\mathbb{R}$. So they are very literally the same function, in the strongest possible sense.